Como hacer un test con mockito de mi clase de conexión
Estoy tratando de hacer un test de mi servicio que simule la conexión y lectura a la base de datos
Todo funciona correctamente cuando ejecuto, pero al hacer el test me da error.
Esta es mi función:
@Service
public class GxCompileImpl implements GxCompileService {


    @Value("${as400.datasource.host}")
    private String hostBD;

    @Value("${as400.datasource.username}")
    private String usernameBD;

    @Value("${as400.datasource.password}")
    private String passBD;

    @Value("${as400.programs.find-pase}")
    private String progNameFindPase;

    @Value("${as400.programs.view-pase}")
    private String progNameViewPase;

    @Value("${as400.programs.list-estados}")
    private String progNameListEstados;

    String CodErrorAS400OK = "00000";

    private final int lenUsername = 10;
    private final int lenNroPase = 7;
    private final int lenNroPag = 4;
    private final int lenCantReg = 4;

    private ConnectionAS400 connAs400;

    @Override
    public FindPaseCabOutDTO findPase(String nroPase, String username, int nroPag, int cantReg) throws Exception {

        ...

        //Instancia de la coneccion
        connAs400 = new ConnectionAS400(hostBD, usernameBD, passBD);
        //Lectura de datos de BD
        List<String> response = connAs400.callProgramMetodo1(progNameFindPase, input);

        String jsonData = connAs400.strGxToJson(jsonStruct, response.get(0));
        
        ...

        return bodyOut;
    }
} 

Este es mi test que he avanzado pero no he logrado hacerlo funcionar:
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class GxCompileServiceTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private GxCompileImpl gxCompile;

        @Test
        @DisplayName("Test para findPase")
        public void testFindPaseOK2() throws Exception {

            List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();
            response.add("U20531      TRAMA DE RESPUESTA");
            response.add("000001");
            response.add("00000");
            response.add("OK");

            ConnectionAS400 connAs400 = Mockito.mock(ConnectionAS400.class);
            Mockito.when(connAs400.callProgramMetodo1(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(response);
            
            FindPaseCabOutDTO result = gxCompile.findPase("32343", "S6717350", 1, 10);

            Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
        }
    }

El error que devuelve es NullPointerException, esto es por que las variables para instanciar ConnectionAS400 están en nulo, sin embargo new ConnectionAS400(hostBD, usernameBD, passBD) solo setea los datos, no prueba ni valida de ninguna forma los parámetros, por lo que aunque se envíen en nulo los parámetros, no debería devolver error hasta que se ejecute callProgramMetodo1 que es la función que justamente quiero simular

hacer la inyección por constructor ayuda a hacer más fácil el testing

Mi consejo es crear un constructor que permita definir todos los atributos. Usando lombok podrías hacer algo como:
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor //genera un constructor con todos los atributos necesarios
public class GxCompileImpl implements GxCompileService {
  ...
}


Y en el test podrás crear una instancia donde tienes todos los atributos con los valores necesarios.
